# Clear Excel Cell if Value less than another Cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone can help, I need to clear cells when then value of is less that a value in another cell. I did use conditional formatting but this messes up calculations further into the sheet.

I used a guide and was able to remove cells when I inputted the fixed integer into the module but am unsure how I adapt this to refer to a cell instead of a fixed number.

Thank you.

Ed

Comment: Please elaborate a bit, your problem descriptions is quiet vague

Comment: Do you need to actually clear a cell, or just have the value = zero or blank? If just have it blank, why not use a formula? `=If(B2>100,"","something else")`

Comment: Also, please attach what you currently have for attempting to solve this problem. If you've tried various methods, maybe also add a brief description of those, so you don't get repeat suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for below, this will take a value from cell B1 and compare against values in Column A, and if the values are less than the value in B1, it will clear the contents of that cell:

```
Sub ClearLowerThan()
    Dim c As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long        
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare you worksheet, amend as required
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column A

    CompareVal = ws.Range("B1").Value
    'get the value to compare against, in this case from cell B1

    Set Rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    'set the range to compare against the value from B1

    For Each c In Rng 'for each cell in the given range
        If c.Value < CompareVal Then c.ClearContents
        'if value of cell is less than the value to compare against, clear the cell contents.
    Next
End Sub
```